# bootstrap cols not lining up in the center of the div

Tags: html, css

My problem is simple, my Bootstrap cols are not lining up in the middle of the `div`.

Have a look at my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="boxes">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div id="box1">
                    Hello
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div id="box2">
                    World
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>


#boxes {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;    
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgba(79, 27, 184, 0.29);
}
#box1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#box2 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've put `col-lg` on 6, which should be 50% of the div per box. But the boxes are clearly not in the center of their cols. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The bootstrap grid needs columns to be inside a `.row` element to work properly. And you should not be applying a max-width on that parent in the first place - use a `.container` element for that.

Comment: Are you talking about horizontal or vertical “centering” here? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your margin in your box2 like this, is it what you're looking for ?

```
#box2 {    
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are working with bootstrap 4 wrap your code with `.row` [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f30w9uwx/)

```css
#boxes {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;    
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgba(79, 27, 184, 0.29);
}
#box1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#box2 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 260px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
        <div id="boxes" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div id="box1">
                    Hello
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div id="box2">
                    World
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
```